# if statement when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Trying to make an if statement in JS that when one of the top 3 buttons changes, it checks which of the bottom 2 has the "active" class. and visa versa

So when I click 30g it will check if option a or option b is active, and then change the price accordingly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm kind of a noob.

```js
$(function(){
  $('ul.nav li').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().find('li.activeBtn').removeClass('activeBtn');
    $(this).addClass('activeBtn');
  });
});

function myFunction(){
  const element = document.getElementById("30");
  const element2 = document.getElementById("no");
  const pricetag = document.getElementById("price");
  
  if(((element.classList.contains("activeBtn")) == true) && ((element2.classList.contains("activeBtn")) == true)){
    pricetag.innerHTML = "€1,00";
  }
}
```

```css
ul.nav a {
  border: 2px solid #E1E8EE;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5E6977;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .5s;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.activeBtn { 
  color: grey;
  font-weight: 1000;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav">
  <li id="30" onclick="myFunction()" class="activeBtn"><a>30g</a></li>
  <li id="70" onclick="myFunction()"><a>70g</a></li>
  <li id="90" onclick="myFunction()"><a>90g</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav">
  <li id="no" class="activeBtn"><a>Zonder kreeftensoep</a></li>
  <li id="yes"><a>Met kreeftensoep</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<div class="product-price">
  <span id="price">148$</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Apart from your issue there must not be a `<footer>` outside the `<body>`.

Comment: @m02ph3u5 You fixed a typo in the user's code: Don't do that. It could be the reason they're asking the question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey while you are right in principle this does not seem to be OP's issue

Comment: Not really clear what you're trying to achieve here. You want to add or deduct from the current product price based on the button clicked?

Comment: the problem is there are 2 rows of buttons. I know how it would work, I just don't know the syntax, this is what I want to happen but not coded right if(button30g.isclicked && buttonOptionA.ContainsClass.Active) { Price=1.00; } else if(button30g.isClicked && buttonOptionB.ContainsClass.Active) { Price=2.00; } if(button70g.isclicked && buttonOptionA.ContainsClass.Active) { Price=3.50; } else if(button70g.isClicked && buttonOptionB.ContainsClass.Active) { Price=4.00; } and then also 1 for the 90g button –

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to update the total price depending on which element is already selected ?

If that's the case, you can use a for loop event binding ->

```
// You should add a '.nav__el' class to your <li> elements in html
const navEls = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__el')

// Bind an event listener to all your buttons
navEls.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {

    const domPrice = document.querySelector('#price')
    // Get the price related to your button
    const price = el.getAttribute('data-price') 
    // Get the current total
    const currentPrice = parseInt(domPrice.innerText)

    if(el.classList.contains('activeBtn')) {
      el.classList.remove('activeBtn')
      domPrice.innerText = `${currentPrice - price}$`
    }
    else {
      el.classList.add('activeBtn')
      domPrice.innerText = `${currentPrice + price}$`
    }

  })
})
```

Comment: uhm no I already solved that problem. I want the price to change when I click a button. So if I click 30g, and the option b is active then it will be 4$ for example, but if I click 30g and option a is active, then it will be 10$.

Comment: Oh ok, I see, you want the price to increase or decrease depending on wich button is selected? So I suggest you store the price somewhere, like in a data-attribute for example.
Check the example above, I just edited it.

Comment: the problem is there are 2 rows of buttons.

I know how it would work, I just don't know the syntax, this is what I want to happen but not coded right




if(button30g.isclicked && buttonOptionA.ContainsClass.Active)
{
Price=1.00;
}   


else if(button30g.isClicked && buttonOptionB.ContainsClass.Active)
{
 Price=2.00;
}    

if(button70g.isclicked && buttonOptionA.ContainsClass.Active)
{
Price=3.50;
}     

else if(button70g.isClicked && buttonOptionB.ContainsClass.Active)
{
 Price=4.00;
}

and then also 1 for the 90g button

Comment: do you understand??